# How to get views from onGroupExpanded

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an expandable listview in my app and I want to do something to a specific group icon once this group is clicked.

I've tried overriding onGroupExpanded() but I dont know how to extract the views from it. All I get passed into this method is the group position but I'm not sure how to continue from there?

this is what i've got

```
@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    View v = ((View) getGroup(groupPosition)).findViewById(R.id.secondImage);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your adapter `extends BaseExpandableListAdapter`, 
in

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(int pos, boolean isExpanded, View v, ViewGroup p) {
```

first, when setting your holder, find your group icon:

```
holder.icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.group_icon);
```

and after that:

```
if (isExpanded) {
    holder.icon.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_1));
} else {
    holder.icon.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_2));
}
```